Can't connect to mysql database from the python code using mysql.connector
I m unable to connect to my database and it gives this error that object is not callable. I did search up the error and even what it means. I changed a lots of stuff in the code but it didn't work for me.
like instead of using the import mysql.connector.connect() to connect to the database I used connection.MySQLConnection() and it still gave the same error. I even changed the variable names because I saw some where that variables could also be an issue some time. It didn't help either, the problem might not be big but I m just having a hard time to fix it.
def Database_connection(self):
        
        dbhost = "localhost"
        dbuser = "test"
        dbpass = "1234"
        database_name ="school"
        
        #CONNECTION OF DB
        self.mdb = mysql.connector.connect(
            
            host = dbhost,
            password = dbpass,
            user = dbuser,

        )
        #Cursor to mysql database
        cursor = self.mdb.cursor()
        
        #Creates database if it doesn't exists
        cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}')
        
        self.mdb = mysql.connector.connect(
            
            host = dbhost,
            password = dbpass,
            user = dbuser,
            db = database_name,
        )
        return self.mdb


def insert_new_student(self):
        
        try:
            conn = self.Database_connection()

            if conn is None:
                return
            
            cursor = conn().cursor()

            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
 
        except mysql.connector.Error as err: #Handles Error

            print(f"Error: {err}")


The Error this code generates is:
line 380, in insert_new_student
    cursor = conn().cursor()
             ^^^^^^
TypeError: 'MySQLConnection' object is not callable


Which one is line 380? My guess is that you need to remove () after conn in conn().cursor()

cursor = conn.cursor(). That’s aside from some other scary lines in the code.  Was this a copy/paste job or a YouTube ‘tutorial’?  I’d strongly recommend understanding what each line is doing; and this may help you understand where you can clean up the scary bits.

Thanks it worked. @s3dev I just started learning python so that's my code looks like a youtube tutorial XD

Instead of cursor = conn().cursor() use conn = self.Database_connection(), You must have copied code from somewhere but forgot to rename the function name. Upvoted you so that you are still able to look for help on this forum

I think the self.mdb is the connection object, so the cursor would be conn.cursor.
Line 380: conn.cursor()
The reason is that an object can not be called, however, it's method can be called and conn in a connection object, yes?
